# Pass command-line argument for a particular Tomcat web-application startup

Tags: spring-boot, tomcat, command-line-arguments, web-deployment, jasypt

For my Spring-Boot project, I have used jasypt library for encrypting my `datasource.password` in `application.properties` file. In my localhost setup, I have configured VM arguments in eclipse and it works completely fine.

```
-Djasypt.encryptor.password
-Djasypt.encryptor.algorithm
```

Now, I want to deploy my application to Tomcat server where I am not able to figure out where to configure these VM arguments so that Tomcat picks them when I click on "start" button from Tomcat Manager GUI.

Read solutions about `setenv.sh` but I think that works at complete Tomcat server level. I need to pass these arguments only for my current application without affecting other applications which are already hosted.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What's the best way to pass arguments to a tomcat instance?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/849713/whats-the-best-way-to-pass-arguments-to-a-tomcat-instance)

Comment: Also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12407163/pass-vm-argument-to-apache-tomcat/34311797

Comment: @MadhuBhat Yes, the question linked in first comment resonates with my requirement. Thanks for sharing it. But the answer to that question is not very clear. How to configure the -D arguments in server.xml or context.xml? Any sample reference if you can share.